# Distance travelled using RFID or similar

Tags: sensor, rf, rfid

I want to know distance travelled by an object (sheet of plywood) passing over head with a resolution of 3cm.
*Plywood is fed down a shoot and slides on a roller ramp, comes to a rest on horizontal plane above sensing element.*

With no discernible features on the the object ultra sound, Lidar, ToF are of no use. I cant add features *i.e. i cant add significantly to the plywood in so far as to add a feature that could be distinguished by ultra sound* and figured that passive RFID tags may be the best route considering their minimal thickness. *I could place visible markers on the plywood if needed*

*Distance between sensor and underside of object is 30cm  which i cant make contact with and all sensing must be done under the plywood board.*

*I need to know how much the object has over or undertravelled beyond the sensing element, absolute position needed*

**My intial thoughts**

The object will come to stop over the reader, and with my minimal understanding of RFID i figure that the tag closest to the reader will be the only one that transmits its unique ID as it'll be the only one with sufficient power. If the distance between each tag is known and kept within 3cm then the distance the object has travelled overhead between stop start and stop will be found.

Image below might better illustrate (not to scale) edited to show smaller RFID with width marginally greater than RFID Tags themselves

[image]

My question is

1) will the tags likely interfere with eachother and try and transmit their ID at the same time

2)any other suggestions to solve this?

Comment: What kind of object? Where is it moving? What are the constraints? Anyway, the RFID solution would be the last one I would look at (other potential methods - optical, magnetic, laser).

Comment: Your diagram shows at least two tags equally close to the reader, so not sure why you think you won't have RF collisions with this method.

Comment: It looks like you may be overthinking this. This sounds like an encoder, but you really should provide better specs. Max speed, distance, absolute position or just distance traveled, height above your "reader"? You say you can't add features, but isn't adding the tags adding features? Would marking the object count as adding features?

Comment: ... May the object be touched? The solution could be as simple as a rotational encoder with a wheel.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a video camera assuming whatever they are not going stupid fast...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Edits added in italics, apologies hope this is a little more detailed, thanks for Q's

Comment: @Martin I've edited picture to show that RFID is little over the width of the tags themselves, which based on the dev boards ive looked at would be true.

Comment: @Tut thanks for the comments, unfortunately i can't touch the plywood. However i like your idea of marking the object, combined with Trevor  comments regarding a camera, this could be a good work around.

Comment: No need to add marks if you use a camera. The surface of the wood will have enough texture that a camera can pick it up. Think of it like a giant optical mouse, they work fine without you drawing lines on your desk.

Comment: I agree, marks may be unnecessary with image processing. For a possibly simpler solution, consider marks with a reflective-object sensor ... a do-it-yourself encoder.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, food for thought (apologies about the initial lack of detail).

Comment: IR or laser seems to be the ideal here. Camera is needlessly complex and RFID is not even a solution to consider.